# Winapi - detectar si una variable tiene espacios en blanco

Tags: c++, winapi

Estoy haciendo un programa donde tengo que crear una cuenta con nombre de usuario y contraseña, uno de los requisitos es que la contraseña no tenga espacios en blanco, hasta ahorita había usado el siguiente código para detectar los espacios en blanco:

```
        wchar_t passwordENT[60]{ '\0' };
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < wcslen(passwordENT); i++) {
            if ((passwordENT[i] > 'A' && passwordENT[i] <= 'Z') || (passwordENT[i] > 'a' && passwordENT[i] <= 'z') || (passwordENT[i] > '0' && passwordENT[i] <= '9'))
            {
                c++;
            }

        }
        if (c == wcslen(passwordENT) - 1)
        {
        }
        else {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"La contraseña tiene espacios en blanco", L"ALERTA", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            break;
        }`
```

Pensaba que funcionaba bien, pero durante el testeo me di cuenta de que si no agrego alguno de los caracteres 'a' , 'A' , '0' de igual manera me detecta que tiene espacios en blanco aunque no tenga.

¿Saben cómo puedo solucionarlo o que estoy haciendo mal? Gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código falla porque al decir **mayor que**, estás excluyendo al valor mencionado.

Por ejemplo, si dices **x > 8**, 8 no es mayor que 8.

Algo similar pasa en tu código, con `passwordENT[i] > 'A'` estás excluyendo la **A**.

Si quieres incluir el valor indicado tienes que usar mayor o igual (`passwordENT[i] >= 'A'`). Lo mismo con los otros caracteres con los que no te funciona.

---

Algunas observaciones:

Si buscas eficiencia no llames reiteradamente a `wcslen`. Puedes llamarla solo una vez y guarda su valor en una variable.

Si lo prefieres, buscar tu mismo el final de la cadena con `passwordENT[i] != 0`. Todas las cadenas deberían terminar en un caracter nulo. El código se vería así:

```
for (int i = 0; passwordENT[i] != 0; i++) {
    if ((passwordENT[i] >= 'A' && passwordENT[i] <= 'Z') || (passwordENT[i] >= 'a' && passwordENT[i] <= 'z') || (passwordENT[i] >= '0' && passwordENT[i] <= '9'))
    {
        c++;
    }
}
```

También sugiero que solo uses las funciones de C cuando no haya una mejor opción en C++. Por ejemplo [`wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) es una estructura con funciones útiles. En tu código se vería así:

```
std::wstring passwordENT;

...

int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < passwordENT.length(); i++) {
    if ((passwordENT[i] >= 'A' && passwordENT[i] <= 'Z') || (passwordENT[i] >= 'a' && passwordENT[i] <= 'z') || (passwordENT[i] >= '0' && passwordENT[i] <= '9'))
    {
        c++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para detectar espacios en blanco también puedes hacer uso de las funciones integradas en la librería estándar:

```
if (std::any_of(passwordENT.begin(), passwordENT.end(), [](wchar_t c) { return c == L' '; }))
{
    // Algun caracter es un espacio
}
```

La función `any_of` recorre `passwordENT` y para cada caracter ejecuta la lambda. Si la lambda devuelve `true` en algún momento, `any_of` deja de evaluar y retorna `true`.

También puedes usar esta utilidad con funciones, si necesitas diseñar chequeos más complejos sin sacrificar legibilidad:

```
bool isValidPasswordChar(wchar_t c)
{
    return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}

if (std::all_of(passwordENT.begin(), passwordENT.end(), isValidPasswordChar))
{
    // La contraseña es válida
}
```

Tanto `any_of` como `all_of` se encuentran en la librería `algorithm`